# Applying Proguard to multiple AAR libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, aar

I'm currently building an Android SDK and I want to distribute it in different artifacts. For example: sdk-core, sdk-auth, etc.

Each one of these artifacts is a .aar library that should only expose those methods and classes that are meant to be used. The rest must be obfuscated.

The goal is that the end user can decide which features he needs based on the libraries he adds as dependency. Something similar to what Google did with play services or Firebase.

I have an Android Studio project with two Android Library modules where "auth" depends on "core".

My problem is that I don't know how to apply Proguard to both modules. If I obfuscate "core", then the "auth" module can't see the required classes anymore.

Is there any way to apply Proguard to multiple modules at the same time and share the mapping ?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.﻿

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, At the end I just decided to merge everything into one .aar library.